# What triggers extensions to say "Use this extension by clicking on this icon"

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Afte completing the installation some Chrome extensions say "Use this extension by clicking on this icon":

[image: uBlock Origin]

Others don't:

[image: Boxel Rebound]

My extension doesn't have this line, but I want it to have it. What's triggering this?

Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Comment: It has a `browser_action` (MV2) or [action](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action) (MV3) section in manifest.json.

Comment: My app (MV3) does have action ("action": {"default_icon": "icon.png"}) in the manifest.json, but still doesn't have that line.

Comment: It must be "default_popup" inside then or chrome.action.onClicked in the background script.